# Como encontrar o vetor correspondente ao ângulo em 3 dimensões?

Tags: matemática, opengl, geometria

Olá,
Estou fazendo um jogo 3D e estou tendo problemas para fazer raycasting em 3D. No caso, quero fazer para a câmera, para saber se não tem nenhum objeto entre a camera e o jogador. Para isto eu preciso encontrar um vértice que represente o ângulo e verificar no mapa se existem obstáculos ou não.
A câmera guarda o angulo de dois eixos: eixo Y (modificado com o movimento do mouse na horizontal, eixo X da tela no plano 2D) e eixo X (modificado com o movimento do mouse na vertical, eixo Y da tela no plano 2D).
Eu consigo fazer raycast de qualquer um destes ângulos sozinhos, mas não consigo juntá-los para fazer raycast em 3 dimensões. O problema é que ambos compartilham o Z (o seno do eixo Y e o cosseno do eixo X). Se eu multiplico os dois entre si, o resultado só fica correto quando o ângulo Y é 0º ou 90º. Se não, ele fica invertido.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que fórmula devo usar para calcular o valor Z?

Comment: Complexo, acho que terá que postar essa pergunta no [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) já que não implica em código, apenas na fórmula.

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado KaduAmaral pela dica, encontrei a fórmula no [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385137/calculate-3d-vector-out-of-two-angles-and-vector-length):

```
x = r cos β sin α
y = r cos β cos α
z = r sin β

Vetor: xî +yĵ +zk̂
```

Comment: Às ordens​​​​​​